# Can I travel using one-way ticket when going to China on a Z-visa?

Tags: china

I have got Chinese Z-Visa. Is it essential for me to buy a round trip ticket or is a one-way ticket OK? I am planning to travel using Thai Airways and I will fly from Lahore, Pakistan holding a Pakistani passport.

Answer (score 3):

With a Z visa you do not require a return ticket. That being said, it is possible that Thai Airways will not be aware of this, and will expect a return ticket to board the flight. Your best bet would be to contact Thai Air and verify their policy on this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer. I am already in china :)